# Media queries in em not affected by the base font size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, font-size

I'm trying to understand why setting a different base font size doesn't affect the EM values for the media queries.

They are acting as the default base font size is 16px, while the rest of the content reacts normally.

Try it yourself:

**Media queries in PX:**
https://jsfiddle.net/sebtp/n8x0tuvq/5/ [OK]

**Media queries in EM:**
https://jsfiddle.net/sebtp/n8x0tuvq/7/ [NOT OK]

**Media queries in REM:**
https://jsfiddle.net/sebtp/n8x0tuvq/10/ [NOT OK]

```
html {
    font-size: 62.5%; /*setting the base font size to 10px*/
}

body {
  background: white;
}
span { 
  font-size:6em; /* 60px, as it should */
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 30em) { /* 480px, should be 300px */
  body {
    background:red;
  }

 @media only screen and (min-width: 40em) { /* 640px should be 400px */
  body {
    background:cyan;
  }

  @media only screen and (min-width: 50em) { /* 800px should be 500px */
  body {
    background:yellow;
  }
```

Comment: I think because you use ems - they are usually done to the parent element size.  As there is no parent element in the media query, it will use the base font size of 16px, rather than the font size set for the body

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get font sizes that are relative to the font-size defined in an `html` rule, you have to use **rem** units, not `em`. `em` is relative to the element itself, and if there is no font-size definition, to the parent/next ancestor which has a font-size definition (which could also be defined in the browsers default settings, BTW).

ADDITION AFTER COMMENT OF OP:

Interesting: Since you define the `html` font size in percent, obviously the browser continues to treat its internal default setting as the root size (from which it derives the rem unit). If you change the font-setting in the `html` rule to a `px` setting, `rem` units will respond accordingly concerning the *font-size*, but the browser still keeps using its default font size (16px) for *horizontal measuring* (at least in Firefox). Have a look here (watch the 12px setting and the comments in the CSS rules):  https://jsfiddle.net/zwc00gtk/2/

ONE MORE ADDITION:

For "regular" horizontal measuring, the rem unit works as expected, in the following example the `.wrap` div with the light-green background is set to `width: 40rem`, which is calculated as 480px when the font--size in `html` is set to `12px`, and even becomes 400px when font-size in `html`is `62.5%` (= 10px)

https://jsfiddle.net/n2dww2mt/1/

So it's only the media queries that won't accept anything else than 16px as the `rem` unit...

Comment: True, I forgot to mention that I tested with REMs as well: https://jsfiddle.net/sebtp/n8x0tuvq/10/

Comment: Intersting, so there isn't really a way to force the base-font-size-rem-units for the media queries? I can only use them REM in media queries based on the default browser font (16)?

Comment: Thanks! But that still weird :D

Comment: I wish the media query `rem` units were based on the `html` font size. This would be great, because developers could decide to use the browser root font, or the html font, rather than being forced to use only browser root font in media queries and html root font in all other stuff. Being stuck with one choice makes design inflexible.